# What is the best way to read files that have dash `-`

Tags: shell, command-line, command

New to linux (self learning) and I was going through some lessons and had  a file that was `- file`. I tried to use `cat -` but didn't work. So after searching I found that I needed to use `cat ./-`

But I don't really understand why and if there is an easier or more proper way to view the file.

So is there a more preferred way to view the contains of the file other than `cat ./-` or is this command the easiest.

*I have a feeling If I stick with it this, this post is going to be that post I look back at in a year or 2 and think, wow I was really new to all this*

Comment: `./-` is probably the best (and most portable) way. For alternatives, see the question Tigger linked. (As to why, it's because various commands attach special meaning to the file name `-`)